# Clearing pivots filters and refreshing connections using python

Tags: python, excel, database

I am trying to partially automate the reporting process. This requires a large amount of data, which after connecting to an external data source (in excel Data - Get Data - From Data base - From Analysis Services and here gives the data needed to connect to Cube) lands in excel (I don't have privileges or will not be given direct, so that I can do it any SQL, I have to download it to this excel first).

Unfortunately, the amount of data I need dumps the whole excel and so I wanted to try to do it with python.

My goal was to first apply filters to the data, so that the appropriate table could be prepared and physically downloaded at all, and then close excel and using python refresh on demand. However, in order for the data to meet my requirements, I need to remove these filters, because I need the entire data set.

I wanted to take off these filters using python, but first of all, I can't find a solution, only refreshing excel code worked for me, while taking off the filters is beyond my reach. Secondly, I'm afraid that even this way it won't make any difference and excel will still crash.

The data is stored by an external provider.

This is what I use for excel connection refreshing:

```
import win32com.client
def refresh_excel_connection(slim_data_path):
    xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application") 
    Workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(slim_data_path)  
    Workbook.RefreshAll()
    xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
    Workbook.Save()
    xlapp.Quit()
    del xlapp
```

Do you have any idea how to approach it?

The download method I mentioned above is the only one I have access to.

Unless there is some other approach that can also work?